# How do I solve this trigonometric equation, step-by-step?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve:

> $x = \arcsin(k) + \arcsin(\sqrt{1-k^{2}} )$

(EDIT) I wrote the wrong power in the question and changed it

Comment: solving for ....?

Comment: It is already solved.

Comment: I am doing it from a book and it says the answer is pi/2. I don't know how they got there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a Triangle with Hypotenuse = $1$ and Opposite = $\sqrt{1-k^2}$ and then convert the second term to arccos

Comment: Drawing the triangle. With opp and hyp as you said, I used pythagoras to find that the adjacent side is k^2.  So I found (not sure though) the arcos equiv as arccos(k^2)?

Comment: Are you sure? it would be $arccos(k)$, not $arccos(k^2)$ ( $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$)

Comment: Oh yeah, of course it is. I forgot to square-root my answer!

Comment: I have now understood it. this is the same as arcsink + arccosk. If let A = arcsink and B = arcosk; then the equation is the equivalent of: A + B = x. Then sin of both sides: sin(A+B) = sin(x). Using the expansion formula and sin^2 + cos^2 =1, I know sinA = k, cosB = k ---  sinB = root of (1-k^2) and cosA also = root of (1-k^2).                                                                                          Then k^2 + 1 - k^2 = sinx,   so sinx = 1, and therefore x = pi/2    @anvit

Answer (score 1):

Hint  :

$$\arcsin (x) +\arccos (x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Do you know how to covert $\arcsin$ into $\arccos$?

Comment: So, I know that cos(90 - x) = sinx, And so arcsinx = pi/2 - arccosx?

Comment: @RHS Can you try to convert $\arcsin(\sqrt{1-k^2})$ into $\arccos(?)$?

Comment: Is it arcos(k^2)?

Comment: @RHS No. It should be $\arccos(\sqrt {k^2})$

Comment: Yeah, I just realised I forgot to square root my answer. So it is arccos(k)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have understood how to get the answer - seen on the Anvit's post.

Comment: @RHS Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rearrange that to $k= \cos(x-\arcsin(k))$ and use $k=\sin (\arcsin k)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the picture of a solution to your question:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pou7L.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! @Sragdharamalini Das

Answer (score 0):

$x=\arcsin\sqrt{1-k^2}+\arcsin k$

Suppose $k>0$

$\sin \left(\arcsin\sqrt{1-k^2}+\arcsin k\right)=\\=\sin\arcsin\sqrt{1-k^2}\cos\arcsin k+\cos\arcsin\sqrt{1-k^2}\sin\arcsin k=\\=\sqrt{1-k^2} \sqrt{1-\sin^2\arcsin k}+k\sqrt{1-\sin^2\arcsin\sqrt{1-k^2}}=\\=(\sqrt{1-k^2})^2+k\sqrt{1-(1-k^2)}=1-k^2+k^2=1$

$\sin x=1$

$x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Hope this can be useful